# FragmentPagerAdapter shows a blank screem, but PagerAdapter works fine

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I have a fragment that instantiates a ViewPager using a FragmentPagerAdapter adapter.

I noticed that occasionally the screen appeared blank, as if the onCreateView() was not returning any views.

So I changed the FragmentPagerAdapter for PagerAdapter and solved the problem.

Does anyone know why? Is it related to nested fragments ?
Any explanation would be welcome.

Regards,

Comment: if you have more than 4 fragments use fragmentpagrstateadapter

Comment: code please, this would be much more easier to understand.